# a call to sspi failed see inner exception. the message received was unexpected or badly formatted in windows 7]

Tags: c#, notifications, push, sspi

I am getting the following error " a call to sspi failed see inner exception. the message received was unexpected or badly formatted in windows 7". i tried all the possible ways but no luck. please check it

Here is the code

```
        int port = 2195;
        String deviceID = "d6c597fcc4e3426993cf29a3a8857efbed3462d5d8e9e32c0f8b387djkdklldk";
        String hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";     // TEST
        //String hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";           // REAL
        string p12FilePassword = "password";
        //        @"cert.p12";
        String certificatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Certificate.p12");


        X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(p12FilePassword) ? new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath)) : new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), p12FilePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);

        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, ValidateServerCertificate, SelectLocalCertificate);
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
            //client.Close();
            //return;
        }
```

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: The inner exception says "the message received was unexpected or badly formatted"

Comment: @TanishaSayyad, I know this is old post however are you able to fix the above error? If yes, can you please share what you did to fix the error. I am getting the same error here and not able to make the code work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post but I recently faced this problem. Application can work on my Windows10 and failed on Windows server 2008r2 and 2012r2.
The solution is get rid off SslStream and use libraries like openssl or bouncycastle for tls connections.